# PHP alternative of Javascript's pop() method

Tags: javascript, php, split

Is there any PHP method to do:

```
var filename = $_POST["filename"];
filename = filename.split(".").pop();
```

How can I do the same above thing in PHP?

Comment: Questions like this should be closed, if people don't bother to Google terms like "PHP array pop".

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
$filetype = array_pop(explode('.',$filename));
```

It will generate an `Only variables should be passed by reference` notice. If you want to get rid of that, you'd need:

```
$fileparts = explode('.',$filename); 
$filetype = array_pop($fileparts);
```

However, the best way to get a file's extension is by using [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo):

```
$filetype = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: `pathinfo()` is just giving me the "."

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: What does `var_dump($filename);` output?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you probably don't need to convert to an array and pop; get the position of the last character, then get the rest of the string. From http://davidwalsh.name/php-file-extension:

```
substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `unset($filename[count($filename) - 1]);`. Which will remove the last element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to do this:

```
$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$file_arr = explode(".",$filename); // may need to escape '.' here, can't remember
$filename = array_pop($file_arr);
```